# Is it possible to call a Python DoFn from a Java ParDo in Apache Beam?

Tags: java, python, apache-beam

Suppose I'm building a Beam pipeline in Java that will run on a DataflowRunner. Is it possible to call a Python DoFn from a Java ParDo? (or to use a Python PTransform in such a setting?) If this functionality doesn't exist out-of-the-box, what would it take to implement it? Writing a custom connector?

Thanks!

Comment: According to a section on Apache's Beam website (update November 2019) there is active and ongoing to support cross-language transforms. It looks like a good bit of progress has been made, but support by DataflowRunner depends on work being done at Google. I'd love to know what the timeline is on that piece. (See Apache link here: https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/connectors-multi-sdk/)